# Running Python File in Elastic Beanstalk uploaded from github

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have just one file `run.py` in `app` folder which I need to run after uploading to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

The upload is done automatically from code pipeline from github.

How do I make Elastic Beanstalk launch this script?

Answer (score 1):

There are **few ways of doing this**, depending no when exactly the script should be run.

You can use `.ebextansions` and [Commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) and [Container commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands):

- Commands: The commands **run before** the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted.
- Container commands: Container commands **run after** the application and web server have been set up and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed.

There also also EB [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) for Amazon Linux 2:

- These are executable files that you deploy as part of your application's source code, and Elastic Beanstalk **runs during various instance provisioning stages**.

A recent AWS blog gives an **excellent example** of how to use cron in EB:

- [How do I create cron jobs on Amazon EC2 instances in Elastic Beanstalk environments?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/)

Comment: Thanks, but I could not wrap my head around these aws specific commands. So, it would be great if you could prove concrete code for that.

Comment: @eugen I added a recent good example from AWS about cron to answer. Hopefully it will help